# class array property value change using find method for all the elements in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a sample code below

```
let arr = [
{ name:"string 1", value:"value1", other: "other1" },
{ name:"string 2", value:"value2", other: "other2" }
];

let obj = arr.find((o, i) => {
       arr[i] = { name: 'new name', value: 'new value', other: 'that' };
    return true; // stop searching
});

  console.log(arr);
```

I want to replace all the array value with name " new name " and value "new value" , right now it is changing only first array index value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` returns the first element of the array which matches the condition. You are returning `true` from your function so it stops iterating after the first index.

When you have to change each value of array to new value. You should use `map()`. return and object from the `map()` function. First copy all the property of the object into the final object using spread oeprator `...` then set the desired properties to new values

```js
let arr = [
{ name:"string 1", value:"value1", other: "other1" },
{ name:"string 2", value:"value2", other: "other2" }
];

const res = arr.map(x => ({...x, name: "new name", value: "new value"}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @PiushShukla You are welcome. Better to read some documentation about all the array methods specifically **iteration methods** before making projects. This will help you alot. You can get a list here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: One more question how to apply filter if we need to change value based on a condition.

Comment: this.state.formOrderItems.map(x => (x.id === ev ? { ...x, isDefault: checked } : x

Comment: @PiushShukla What is problem in the above approach?

Comment: Nothing , but one of condition i need to filter data based on condition .

Comment: @PiushShukla You need to use `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new array but instead modify the `arr` itself then you can use forEach like this:

```js
let arr = [
    { name:"string 1", value:"value1", other: "other1" },
    { name:"string 2", value:"value2", other: "other2" }
    ];
    
    arr.forEach((element) => {
     element.name = 'new name';
     element.value = 'new value';
     element.other = 'that';
    })
    console.log(arr);
```